# Efficiently creating a list of formatted hex values

Tags: python, performance, beginner, python-3.x, formatting

My background is in C, and I'm finally learning this new-fangled "Python" that all the cool kids are talking about.

I want to create a list of formatted hexadecimal values like so:

```
['0x00','0x01','0x02','0x03' (...) '0xfe','0xff']
```

Please note that the leading zero's *shouldn't* be stripped. For example, I want `0x03`, not `0x3`.

My first successful attempt was this:

```
hexlist=list()
tempbytes = bytes(range(256))
for value in tempbytes:
    hexlist.append("0x" + tempbytes[value:value+1].hex())
del tempbytes
```

But, *wow* this is ugly.  Then I tried to make it more Pythonic ("Pythony"?) like so:

```
hexlist = ["0x"+bytes(range(256))[x:x+1].hex() for x in bytes(range(256))]
```

My thoughts:

1. OMG! That's *harder* to read, not easier!
2. Not only that, but I had to invoke `range` twice, which I assume is inefficient.
3. I bet there's a much better way that I haven't been exposed to yet...

My questions:

1. Is the second much less efficient?
2. Is there a better way to do this?
3. What's the best thing to do here in keeping with python style?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shortest and most readable way to do it would probably be

```
hexlist = [hex(x) for x in range(256)]
```

---

Time

Your first : 0.1  ms per loop for \$10^5\$ loops

Your second: 1    ms per loop for \$10^5\$ loops

The above  : 0.02 ms per loop for \$10^5\$ loops

---

I'm unable to com up with a worse example, but there is always a worse way to do it, exactly as there is always preferable way to do it.

**Edit**
To do this with filled zeros I would suggest to treat the first 10 numbers as a special case.

```
hexlist = [hex(x) if x > 15 else "{:#04x}".format(x) for x in range(256)]
```

new time: 0.04 ms. Even if it isn't as pretty.

---

**Edit:**

And when considering that format can format binary numbers, why not hex?

```
hexlist = ["{:#04x}".format(x) for x in range(256)]
```

I guess that this is hard coded for this range, but anyway.

Time: 0.1ms for per loop for \$10^5\$ loops.

---

**And more edits**

Using **old style:**.

```
hexlist = ["0x%02x" % n for n in range(256)]
```

Time: 0.08ms per loop for \$10^5\$ loops.

---

And specifically generating what we want.

```
hexlist = ["{:#04x}".format(x) for x in range(16)] + \
              [hex(x) for x in range(16, 256)]
```

Time: 0.03ms per loop for \$10^5\$ loops.

Comment: Excellent, Simon, thank you.  Unfortunately, this strips off the leading zeros from the first 10 values.  I wasn't clear in my question: I would like `0x03`, for example, instead of `0x3`.  I've updated the question...

Comment: Maybe not as pretty as your first method, but a whole lot prettier than either of mine!  :-D  Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help, it was an very interesting question!

Comment: For roughly 0.13 ms per loop (over 10^5 loops), using "old-style" formatting strings, `["0x%02x" % n for in in range(256)]` is short, readable and (probably) fast enough for once-off generation.

Comment: Both your edits are using the [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings), `format(x, "#04x")` is the same as `"{:#04x}".format(x)`. Also either way you could change them to `'0x{:0>{}x}'.format(5, 2)`, or `"{:#0{}x}".format(5, 4)` if you don't want a static length.

Comment: Tank you. @peilonrayz, ahh! thank you for clarifying that and the very handy link. Din't know that format was so versatile!

Comment: Very nice, Simon.  I've learned a lot from seeing your different solutions. Thanks again :)